# Why Does An Empty SceneKit Scene Have High Polygon Count?

Tags: ios, 3d, polygon, scenekit, scene

Why does an empty scene have 2k-5k polies?
Even the start template with the "ship" shows 2k-5k...

[image]

Comment: Please post the code / project

Comment: Simply start a new SceneKit game and run it in Xcode 10. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well basically because the geometry contains all those polygons. Open the asset and see.[image]

Comment: Wow, and so it does... I'm pretty sure I tried to remove it from the scene and then build and it was still the same... But I just ran it again without the ship and it went down to 47.

Answer (score 0):

> The `Default Template` does have not-empty scene if there's a `SHIP` model. It has a scene containing a 3D geometry and that geometry has **`2.8K polygons`** (as well as 5.8K vertices).

Check it in the ***Inspector*** :

[image]